# Streaming data in wso2 api manager 3.2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Good day!
I was asked to publish an rtsp stream on wso2 api manager 3.2, for example this: rtsp: //wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4: BigBuckBunny_115k.mov. Naturally - this does not work, I do not receive rtsp data proxied through wso2 api manager 3.2. Am I getting it right, this shouldn't work? I want to know if it is possible to receive multimedia data through wso2 api manager 3.2?
And also I want to know if it is possible to receive any other streaming data through wso2 api manager 3.2, for example, stock quotes? Or is this only possible in version 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, [WSO2 API Manager](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/streaming/streaming-overview/) or [WSO2 Streaming Integrator](https://wso2.com/integration/streaming-integrator/) products (even the latest versions) are not supporting such RTSP streams.

It is possible to [create WebSocket APIs using WSO2 APIM 3.2.0](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/design-api/create-api/create-a-websocket-api/), where streams will use `ws` (or `wss`) protocols. If your stock quote data are coming from a server via a WebSocket channel, you can create a WebSocket API in WSO2 API Manager 3.2 and consume them.

[WSO2 API Manager's latest version 4.0](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/create-api/create-streaming-api/streaming-api-overview/) has support for proxying WebSocket and SSE (Server-Sent Events) streams as managed APIs by default. Unlike in API Manager 3.2, *resources* are supported for these types of APIs as well. So in this case, if your stock quote data are coming from the server in the form of WebSocket or Server-Sent Events, you can directly proxy your server via WSO2 API Manager 4.0.

If you are getting stock quote data from your server via other protocols such as Kafka, MQTT, HTTP, JMS and etc, you can use [WSO2 Streaming Integrator](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/streaming/streaming-overview/) (which is an integration component of API Manager 4.0) to switch from those protocols - to WebSocket or SSE; and then you can proxy the switched stream. [Here is an example of switching Kafka to WebSocket, and exposing it as a WebSocket API](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/use-cases/streaming-tutorials/expose-a-kafka-topic-as-a-managed-websocket-api/).

You can find more information from [here](https://wso2.com/library/articles/streaming-api-support-with-wso2-api-manager/).